# Hide complex read only property from Swagger UI

Tags: swagger, openapi, swashbuckle.aspnetcore

I'm using `Swashbuckle.AspNetCore 6.1.4` OpenAPI library in a .NET 5 mvc/api project.

I've got an endpoint with a filter model that Swagger uses to create query parameters documentation.

The problem is that there is a complex property (a custom object) that is being displayed.

This is a base abstract class

```
public abstract class BaseFilter
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The page number
    /// </summary>
    /// <example>1</example>
    public int Page { get; init; } = 1;
    
    /// <summary>
    /// The number of items per page
    /// </summary>
    /// <example>20</example>
    public int Count { get; init; } = 20;

    /// <summary>
    /// The flag that indicates whether sort is ascending (default) or descending
    /// </summary>
    /// <example>false</example>
    public bool IsDescending { get; init; } = false;
    
    /// <summary>
    /// The case insensitive field to sort by
    /// </summary>
    /// <example>name</example>
    public string? SortBy { get; init; } = null;

    // I DON'T WANT TO DISPLAY THIS
    public Pagination Pagination => new() {PageNumber = Page, PageSize = Count};
}
```

and my filter that inherites the base class and inherits also the complex property

```
public class BrandFilter
    : BaseFilter
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The case insensitive name
    /// </summary>
    /// <example>foo</example>
    public string? Name { get; init; } = null;
}
```

Swagger UI is showing this (see image)
[image]

which I want to hide.

There are several outdated threads over there that use an `ISchemaFilter` that excludes any property with a given attribute. This does not work.

In fact, if I add the following in my `SwaggerGenOptions`

```
c.SchemaFilter<SampleFilter>();
```

and the filter

```
private class SampleFilter
    : ISchemaFilter
{
    public void Apply(OpenApiSchema schema, SchemaFilterContext schemaFilterContext)
    {
        if (schema.Properties is null || !schema.Properties.Any())
        {
            return; 
        }

        // it never reaches here

        // TODO logic to remove properties with X attribute or with a specific name
    }
}
```

the `OpenApiSchema` appears to have 0 properties always.

I have tried jsonIgnoring it, (not using newtonsoft) without any luck either.

**How can I prevent swagger from taking into account that read only complex property?**

PS: This is my swagger config

```
public static IServiceCollection AddOpenApi(this IServiceCollection services)
{
    var mainAssemblyName = typeof(Startup).Assembly.GetName().Name;
    var applicationAssemblyName = typeof(BaseFilter).Assembly.GetName().Name;
    
    services.AddSwaggerGen(
        c =>
        {
            c.SwaggerDoc(
                "v1",
                new OpenApiInfo
                {
                    Title = mainAssemblyName,
                    Version = "v1",
                    Description = "Client Query Service",
                    Contact = new OpenApiContact
                    {
                        Name = "Foo",
                        Email = "diegosasw@test.com"
                    }
                });

            var xmlCommentsWebApi = Path.Combine(System.AppContext.BaseDirectory, $"{mainAssemblyName}.xml");
            c.IncludeXmlComments(xmlCommentsWebApi);
            var xmlCommentsApplication = Path.Combine(System.AppContext.BaseDirectory, $"{applicationAssemblyName}.xml");
            c.IncludeXmlComments(xmlCommentsApplication);

            var availableStatuses = Enum.GetValues<Status>().Where(x => x != Status.None);
            var statusParameters = 
                availableStatuses
                    .Select(x => new OpenApiString(x.GetDisplayName()))
                    .Cast<IOpenApiAny>().ToList();
            
            c.MapType<Status>(
                () =>
                new OpenApiSchema
                {
                    Type = "string",
                    Enum = statusParameters,
                    Nullable = true
                });
            
            c.SchemaFilter<SampleFilter>();
        });
    
    return services;
}

public static void UseOpenApi(this IApplicationBuilder app, string assemblyPath)
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI(c => c.SwaggerEndpoint($"{assemblyPath}/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "Client Query Service v1"));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer was simpler than what I thought.

Swashbuckle honours accessibility. So it was enough with setting that property to `internal`.

I still wonder why the `OpenApiSchema` contains no properties, but the original problem has been solved.